# What is the legal term for someone who performs work in return for money, regardless of whether the man or woman is an employee or contractor?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms, labor-law, labor

As you know, in the United States, ***contractors*** and ***employees*** are very different.

The ***contractors*** do work, but often do **NOT** receive any health insurance.

I was reading that the term ***principle*** is used for someone who hires contractors and/or employees regardless of whether the people working are contractors or whether the people working are employees.

What is the legal term for someone who performs the essential functions of the position, who receives wages, salary, or other financial compensation, regardless of their status as a ***contractor*** or ***employee***?

In other words, what umbrella term represents the union of the set (or category) of all ***contractors*** and the set of all ***employees***?

Comment: *principal* rather than *principle*

Answer (score 3):

As far as the language is concerned, the term is **worker**.

But it is not used much in legal context precisely because of its ambiguity, and the ubiquitous need to be clear whether employee or contractor is meant.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

If this kind of entity is defined in a contract, one could use any term to have the meaning you ask about, like "worker." One could even create a contractually defined term "employee" to also expressly *include* what are otherwise only considered "contractors" (although this could get confusing given the overlap in terms and the inability of the contractual provisions to actually vary the statutory meanings).

In some contexts, it might even be clearest to not define an umbrella term and to expressly state "employee or contractor."

Statutes might also provide a defined term encompassing the scope you ask about. E.g. Ontario's *[Occupational Health and Safety Act](https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/90o01#BK0)* defines "worker" to include

> A person who performs work or supplies services for monetary compensation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the counterpart to "principal," which is "[agent](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/agent#:%7E:text=An%20agent%20is%20a%20person,further%20information%2C%20see%20Agency%20Law.)."

Note, though, that this term applies to people in contexts other than performing tasks for money.

Answer (score 0):

### Worker

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

As defined in Work Health and Safety legislation, it includes what you are after but is quite a bit broader:

> **7   Meaning of “worker”**
>
> (1)  A person is a worker if the person carries out work in any capacity for a person conducting a business or undertaking, including work as—
>
> (a)  an employee, or
>
> (b)  a contractor or subcontractor, or
>
> (c)  an employee of a contractor or subcontractor, or
>
> (d)  an employee of a labour hire company who has been assigned to work in the person’s business or undertaking, or
>
> (e)  an outworker, or
>
> (f)  an apprentice or trainee, or
>
> (g)  a student gaining work experience, or
>
> (h)  a volunteer, or
>
> (i)  a person of a prescribed class.
>
> (2)  For the purposes of this Act, a police officer is—
>
> (a)  a worker, and
>
> (b)  at work throughout the time when the officer is on duty or lawfully performing the functions of a police officer, but not otherwise.
>
> (3)  The person conducting the business or undertaking is also a worker if the person is an individual who carries out work in that business or undertaking.
>
> **Note—**
>
> A person may be both a worker, within the meaning of this section, and a person conducting a business or undertaking within the meaning of section 5.

A person controlling a business or undertaking is often a principal (not a principle - you hope your principal has principles but it’s not required).